# Qt File Browser based on QML

Tags: qt, browser, filesystems, qml, qfilesystemmodel

It is easy to implement a file browser  by using QFileSystemModel. But the listview UI is not pretty. So I want to implement a file browser using QML. the QML has model/view support. But how to display the filesystem tree in QML? Any clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Since Qt5.5 we have `TreeView` QML component available,

`main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
TreeView {
    anchors.fill: parent
    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Name"
        role: "fileName"
        width: 300
    }
    model: my_model
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
QFileSystemModel model;
model.setRootPath("/");
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("my_model", &model);
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think its kind of late, but still it might help some one.

I recently created QML based filedialog for my project for Symbian using Qt Quick Components. Its implementation is [here](https://gitorious.org/kunaltest/kunaltest/trees/master/filedialog),

And [here is sample application](http://kunalmaemo.blogspot.com/2012/02/qml-filedialog-for-symbian.html),